# Convert Excel file to csv in Spark 1.X

Tags: excel, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-1.6, spark-excel

Is there a tool to convert Excel files into csv using Spark 1.X ? 
got this issue when executing this tuto
https://github.com/ZuInnoTe/hadoopoffice/wiki/Read-Excel-document-using-Spark-1.x

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/zuinnote/hadoop/office/format/mapreduce/ExcelFileInputFormat
        at org.zuinnote.spark.office.example.excel.SparkScalaExcelIn$.convertToCSV(SparkScalaExcelIn.scala:63)
        at org.zuinnote.spark.office.example.excel.SparkScalaExcelIn$.main(SparkScalaExcelIn.scala:56)
        at org.zuinnote.spark.office.example.excel.SparkScalaExcelIn.main(SparkScalaExcelIn.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.zuinnote.hadoop.office.format.mapreduce.ExcelFileInputFormat
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Comment: have you added dependency `https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.zuinnote/hadoopoffice-fileformat/1.0.0` to job's classpath?

Answer (score 1):

Spark is unable to find `org.zuinnote.hadoop.office.format.mapreduce.ExcelFileInputFormat` File format class in classpath.

Supply below dependency to spark-submit using `--jars` parameter-

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.zuinnote/hadoopoffice-fileformat -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.zuinnote</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoopoffice-fileformat</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

**Command:**

```
spark-submit --jars hadoopoffice-fileformat-1.0.4.jar  \
#rest of the command arguments
```

Comment: I am using sbt and I added the dependency but I still have the same problem

Comment: is jar present in driver and executor classpath?

Comment: SPark UI-> Environment tab -> check entries in 'spark.driver.extraClassPath' and spark.executor.extraClassPath properties

Answer (score 0):

You have to build a fat jar that contains all the necessary dependencies. The example project on the HadoopOffice page shows how you build one. One you build the fat/uber jar you simply use it in Spark summit.